# Tethered Shooting and Monitor - Nikon 3DX

Tags: nikon, tethering, monitors

I am a newbie to DSLR and am using a friends Nikon 3DX. I'm successfully shooting tethered to a Windows laptop, capturing images to the SD and PC at the same time. I don't have any problem with this, but when I untether the camera (to get a shot I can't get when connected with a cable) my Nikons monitor stays disabled as though I was still tethered. I cant seem to get the monitor to turn back on again unless I turn off the camera and turn it on again.

Is this expected behaviour for un-tethering or am I just missing something simple ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Ok - I found a simple answer - I just need to press the Play button to reactivate the monitor.